# Laravel 4 relationship and events

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having an issue with Eloquent relationship. The relationship is... Each User can have an Owner which is also a user.

When I try to fetch User with Parent:

On *nix OS and PHP 5.4.20, I get same User as Parent so parent and user both are same.

Whereas on PHP5.4.7 (Win 7 if that matters), it returns correct data. By the way this code is an Event Handler of some event.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface, PresentableInterface {
  protected $fillable = array(
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 're_type_password', 'birth_date',
    'phone', 'address', 'state', 'city', 'zip', 'profile_pic', 'owner_id', 'can_edit_appointments',
    'can_accept_invitations', 'can_edit_profile', 'can_receive_notification', 'is_active', 'is_admin', 'token', 'failed_login_attempts_count'
  );

  public function __construct($validator = null, $subAccountValidator = null)
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->validator = $validator ?: App::make('ReminderMillie\Services\Validators\UserValidator');
    $this->subAccountValidator = $subAccountValidator ?: App::make('ReminderMillie\Services\Validators\SubAccountValidator');
  }


  public function getDates()
  {
      return array('created_at', 'updated_at', 'birth_date');
  }


  /**
   *  Relations
   */
  public function business()
  {
    return $this->hasOne('Business', 'owner_id');
  }

  public function parent()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'owner_id');
  }

  public function subAccounts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('User', 'owner_id');
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the `User` model with us?

Comment: Sure. http://laravel.io/bin/kon4m

Comment: Can you also share the code where you're querying the relationship?  that model looks right

Comment: Sure. http://laravel.io/bin/JyLdo

Issue is on line # 53

Comment: I can`t see any reason why it would do that.. is the data in the DB the same between the two machines (the *nix & windows 7 machines)?

Comment: Yes it is correct. I have the same DB on both Windows, Ubuntu.

It works fine on Windows. I don't think that should matter but just saying.

Comment: A known problem in windows is that files name are case insensitive, so be sure to check that classes files are named correctly

Comment: Can you post the actual query being generated? `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` -- and also post your database structure/migration for the users table (showing the owner_id field).

Answer (score 0):

I think you inverse is incorect...

please check this

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function subAccounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User', 'id', 'owner_id');
}
```